# Fix tab order when flagging posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, flags

When I enter content into a multiline textbox (eg, answering a question), I instinctively press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the message.

In most contexts, this works fine, tabbing to the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button and pressing it.

However, when flagging a post, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches to the [cancel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76535/fix-tab-order-when-flagging-posts) link instead of the <kbd>Flag *Post*</kbd> button, and I lose the text that I entered.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: This will be pushed in the next build.

Comment: I was about to post the same, It made me kind of crazy too! good catch!

Comment: Damn it, I up-voted but now I keep canceling the flags! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be pushed in the next build.

<sub>(So it's not unanswered)</sub>